# Adding multiple languages in a website

Tags: php, multilingual

I want to add multiple languages to my site.
I read somewhere that I can use translator(Google or babelfish) but I don't like this way.
Can anyone suggest me different ways?

Answer (score 1):

You could learn the language and translate it yourself. Besides that you will need to use a translator.

Answer (score 1):

You'll want to read up a bit on internationalization and localization (often referred to as i18n L10n).  You'll need code to support serving your various translatinons, based on your users' preferences.  You'll also want to give some thought to handling things like date and currency formats.

As far as PHP tools, you've got the [gettext](http://us.php.net/gettext) stuff, which can be compiled in to PHP.  Gettext works, but was designed to handle translating interface text for locally-installed software -- it doesn't transition to web sites/apps terribly well.

There's also [Zend_Translate](http://framework.zend.com/manual/en/zend.translate.html), which is a pretty good library, and can easily be used without most of the rest of the Zend Framework.  You might want to look at Zend_Locale and Zend_Date, as the three can play together nicely.

Answer (score 0):

You could integrate a translation interface to your site and let the users of your site create their own translation. This way, you get the translation for free.

Or, as an alternative, you could open your website logic to a community (i.e. make it open source) and let it translate by them...

Answer (score 0):

Another way would be to hire someone to translate it into their language :)

Answer (score 0):

if you have members in your site, do what FB is doing ..
they ask the members to help translating to their language, they put the phrases for them, and collect the translations + votes (whether the translation is good or there's better translation).